# Remove input on click in this specific code

Tags: jquery, input

I have this code that works fine, each time I click on "Add field" it will add new input field.

But I can't figure out how to implement the code to remove those fields if clicked on "Remove field".

Anyone that can help?

```
<a id="add-another" href="#">Add field</a>
<a id="remove-field" href="#">Remove field</a>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $field = $('.iphorm_1_3'); 
    $field.attr('name', $field.attr('name') + '[]');

    $('#add-another').click(function () {
        var $clone = $field.clone();
        $clone.val('').css({ display: 'block' }).appendTo($field.parent());
        return false;
    });

    $('#remove-field').click(function () {
      WHAT TO ADD HERE TO REMOVE THEM ONE BY ONE IF CLICKED?
    });


});
```

Here is example of the form on this test page:
http://woodpharmacy.fusionidea.com/dddddddd/

Comment: So when you press `remove-field` you want to remove from bottom or from top?

Comment: I'd like from bottom

Comment: Gave you my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. Since you have a variable `$field` you can find its `siblings` and select the last sibling using `:last` selector and remove it.

```
$('#remove-another').click(function (e) {
  $field.siblings(":last").remove();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit:** Your webpage has `remove-another` as id but in question you have posted `remove-field`.

Comment: Removing and hiding are 2 completely different things. You might want to clarify that with OP.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I am removing it right.. Thats what the OP wants

Comment: You had `.hide()` when I made my comment. Since you edited your answer already, just ignore it.

Comment: Now the complete code is this but for some reason it doesn't work:

Comment: No errors. This code is part of quform plugin, they give explanation how to add fields but not how to remove them, and i wanted to try. However it doesn't work with this code

Comment: @MaraBarn your question has error.  your webpage has an id `remove-another` for remove link, But in question you have posted `remove-field`. Change this and it must work